# Documentation about rd.lvm, rd.luks, and rd.md kernel boot parameters

Tags: grub

I was searching for documentation on how the options `rd.lvm.lv`, `rd.luks.uuid`, options work, but could not find anything relevant. The [official GRUB documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html) does not mention them.

After installing Fedora 20 I had the following in `/etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="rd.luks.uuid=luks-********* rd.lvm.lv=VolGroup01/root rd.lvm.lvVolGroup01/swap ..."
```

Why can multiple `rd.lvm.lv` options can occur? Can I use `rd.lvm.uuid` instead of `rd.lvm.lv`? Such questions come into mind.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The options in question seem to be defined in the kernel itself. [This kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/boot/dracut/dracut.html#dracutcmdline7) covers them:

> **rd.lvm.lv=**
>
> only activate the logical volumes with the given name. rd.lvm.lv can be specified multiple times on the kernel command line.
>
> **rd.luks=0**
>
> disable crypto LUKS detection
>
> **rd.luks.uuid=**
>
> only activate the LUKS partitions with the given UUID. Any "luks-" of the LUKS UUID is removed before comparing to . The comparisons also matches, if  is only the beginning of the LUKS UUID, so you don’t have to specify the full UUID. This parameter can be specified multiple times.
>
> **rd.md=0**
>
> disable MD RAID detection
>
> **rd.md.imsm=0**
>
> disable MD RAID for imsm/isw raids, use DM RAID instead
>
> **rd.md.ddf=0**
>
> disable MD RAID for SNIA ddf raids, use DM RAID instead
>
> **rd.md.conf=0**
>
> ignore mdadm.conf included in initramfs
>
> **rd.md.waitclean=1**
>
> wait for any resync, recovery, or reshape activity to finish before continuing
>
> **rd.md.uuid=**
>
> only activate the raid sets with the given UUID. This parameter can be specified multiple times.

`rd.lvm.uuid` does not appear to be supported.